# Django não está salvando os usuarios no banco de dados

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, django

Estou realizando um projeto com Django e utilizando o postgreSQL como banco de dados. Criei uma app **accounts** para o cadastramento de usuário, porém não está cadastrando no banco de dados e não aparece no **django admin** Segue os trechos de códigos. Se puderem ajudar, agradeço muito!!

Outra questão também, quando fiz um usuário pelo shell ele criou normal...

**Accounts**

-*Views*

```
def add_user(request):
    template_name = 'accounts/add_user.html'
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save(commit=False)
            f.set_password(f.password)
            f.save()
            messages.success(request, "Usuário salvo com sucesso!")
    form = UserForm()
    context ['form'] = form 
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

-*Models*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    cell_phone = models.CharField('Celular', max_length=16)

    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Perfil do Usuário'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

-*Forms*

```
from django import forms 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import UserProfile

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = {'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password'}

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['user']
```

**Configuração do DB em Settings**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME', 'projeto4db'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER', '...'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS', '...'),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**Template de Adicionar Usuário**

```html
{% load static %}

{% load widget_tweaks  %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Cadastrar</title>

    <!-- Font Icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

    <!-- Main css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/adicionar.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="main">

        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="sign-up-content">
                <form method="POST" action="." class="signup-form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    
                    <h2 class="form-group">Cadastre-se</h2>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.first_name.id_for_label }}">Nome</label>
                        {{ form.first_name|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"autofocus" }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.last_name.id_for_label }}">Sobrenome</label>
                        {{ form.last_name|add_class:"form-control" }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}">Usuário</label>
                        {{ form.username|add_class:"form-control" }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">E-mail</label>
                        {{ form.email|add_class:"form-control" }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}">Senha</label>
                        {{ form.password|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"type:password" }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-textbox">                      
                        <button type="submit" class="submit">Cadastrar usuário</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <p class="loginhere">
                    Já tem uma conta?<a href="{% url 'accounts:user_login' %}" class="loginhere-link"> Entrar </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' %}"></script>
</body><!-- This templates was made by Colorlib (https://colorlib.com) -->
</html>
```

Comment: ola, fez algum teste salvando no sqlite ? vai que é um problema no drive do db.

Comment: opa, voltei para o sqlite (default do django) e continua a mesma coisa, não ta salvando. Criei até um outro projeto do zero com o sql e não salvou

Comment: fui reler o tópico e você falou " e não aparece no django admin " por acaso você  se lembrou de rodar o makemigrations e migrate ? para o model  EX:  python manage.py makemigrations --name changed_my_model your_app_label

Comment: Já tinha feito também, porém não mudou em nada... Fiz de novo e continua

Answer (score 0):

Você esqueceu de usar o decorator @csrf_protect
[Documentação do django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/)

```
@csrf_protect
def add_user(request):
template_name = 'accounts/add_user.html'
context = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.set_password(f.password)
        f.save()
        messages.success(request, "Usuário salvo com sucesso!")
form = UserForm()
context ['form'] = form 
return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: Essa prática não mudou em nada...